# CS50 Plurality Problem, error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'

Tags: cs50

Trying to solve the pset3 plurality problem for the CS50 class, line 93 of my code has been the issue, I'm having some trouble solving the last part of the problem set, printing the winner.

I think the vote totals section is okay, but I can't get the code right for the winners section. When I run the code I receive the following error message:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'i' printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;

    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
            candidates[i].votes++;
    }

    return true; 
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int maxvote = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i <  candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > maxvote)
            maxvote = candidates[i].votes;
    }

    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` variable is defined only within the context of your loop. When the loop is over, where your print statement tries to print `candidates[i].name` but `i` is not defined anymore. Just like how you save your max number of votes, you also need to save your candidate index in a value declared outside of your loop.

```
int maxvote = 0; 
int winnerIndex;

for (int i = 0; i <  candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (candidates[i].votes > maxvote) {
        maxvote = candidates[i].votes;
        winnerIndex = i;
    }
}
printf("%s\n", candidates[winnerIndex].name);
```

Comment: Ahh, okay I read and rereads the comment and watched some of the lectures again. I see what you mean when the old code was outside of the loop. I iterated again the candidate_count after setting maxvote = candidates[i].votes.